# Hibernate Persistence in Tomcat using User Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, jta

When I use the below config I get the exception `Name [jdbc/JAWSDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]`. Also I have added all the required settings as shown below.

Persistence looks like below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPresistance">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/JAWSDB</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.hibernate.model.Message</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Controller loads the entity manger using the persistence file :

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{name}")
    public Response sayHello(@PathParam("name") String msg) {
        String output = "Hello, " + msg + "!";
        Context initContext;
        try {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPresistance");
            initContext = new InitialContext();
            UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction)initContext.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
            tx.begin();
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            Message message = new Message();
            message.setText("Hello World!");
            em.persist(message);
            tx.commit();
            // INSERT into MESSAGE (ID, TEXT) values (1, 'Hello World!')
            em.close();

        } 
}
```

Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- url: The JDBC connection url for connecting to your MySQL database. -->

    <Resource name="jdbc/JAWSDB" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30"
        maxWaitMillis="10000" username="root"
        password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />

    <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"/>
    <Transaction factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>

</Context>
```

Web.xml :

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <!-- Define ServletContainer of Jersey -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Define the ResourceConfig class -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.hibernate.app.Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all the URLs to the Jersey ServletContainer -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/JAWSDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

Can you please tell me what I am missing here. I feel loading the User Transaction from the context resource is not having the data base resource injected into it as it is kept as a separate resource in the context.

Added exception stack trace.

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/JAWSDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:140)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:97)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your persistence.xml

from

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/JAWSDB</jta-data-source>
```

to

```
<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/JAWSDB</jta-data-source>
```

and try again

Comment: Am getting the same exception after changing as mentioned in my persistence.xml

Comment: what is your persistence provider? May be you can refer to this: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial for the persistence-unit section transaction-type and the provider

Comment: I am using hibernate so it should be HibernatePersistenceProvider. But not sure how the provider is invoked and its relationship with the current problem of not finding my JNDI datasource.